# What controls the timing of the Windows Certificate Services event "Close to expiration" ID 1003?

Tags: windows-server-2019, windows-event-log, ad-certificate-services, eventviewer

I have a Windows Server which started logging this warning event 36/37 days before a certificate's expiry date and I would like to understand what controls/sets this timing and how it can be configured.

The certificate in question was not auto-enrolled.

Ultimately, I would like to use this event to send a notification X days before the cert is going to expire.

The source of this event in Event Viewer is CertificateServicesClient-Lifecycle-System>Operational

See here for more context:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14250.certificate-services-lifecycle-notifications.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The certificate is considered as "about to expire" in Windows after it reaches 90% of its validity. You can configure this in GPO as specified in referenced TechNet Wiki article's "Settings for Autoenrollment added to Group Policy" section: `Computer/User Configuration, Windows Settings, Security Settings, Public Key Policies, Certificate Services Client - Auto-Enrollment`.

Comment: Does that "log expiry events" setting in the Enrollment Configuration Policy apply for non auto-enrolled certificates like in my case? or if the GPO is not enabled?

Comment: I just checked and the server in question isn't in the scope of any of our auto enrollment policies. I'm speculating that 90% remaining validity might be a implicit default and  I might need to have that GPO applied to the server to adjust it?

Comment: If policy is not applied, then 90% is default value.

Comment: Thanks! that bears out in my testing.